# Show Word document as web page in SharePoint

Tags: word

I'd like to display a Word document with tables and images on SharePoint as a web page. The Word document is updated regularly.

When I save the file as "Web Page" or "Web Page, Filtered" from Word, it displays perfectly fine when simply opened in any browser.

However, when opening the same *.HTML file from a SharePoint library, the character encoding seems to be broken, and in addition, all the images contained on the page are not displayed.

What should I do to display the Word-created HTML file correctly as a web page in SharePoint?

In the meantime, I found this:

- [Convert a Word document to a Web page in Microsoft Office SharePoint
  Server 2007](https://web.archive.org/web/20100305210302/http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepointserver/HA101637801033.aspx)
- [How to enable document conversion from Word to HTML
  in SharePoint 2010](http://alstechtips.blogspot.com/2013/10/how-to-enable-document-conversion-from.html)

I have not found anything like this for a more recent version of SharePoint. Are the above methods for publishing Word files as web pages still applicable to SharePoint today?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using SharePoint pages for content that is primarily viewed via a web browser, pages support tables, images etc. Displaying a word document as a web page doesn't really make much sense since it's not designed for web content, it's used for documents.

Comment: Thanks for not posting answers along the lines of "what you are trying to do does not make sense". This is about a Word document that is A) updated all the time, and B) displays PERFECTLY as a web page directly in any browser -- only not in SharePoint

Comment: Chrome or other browsers don't open docx files directly in the browser natively. You can try this yourself by going to a Word document, right click and "Open with" Chrome or any browser (it'll either prompt to download the file or ask you to open a client app). There is of course plugins and SharePoint uses Word Online to display word files in browser. Word files are not web pages, where as SharePoint pages are.

Comment: Just stop it. It has been possible for decades to save any Word document as a web page simply and directly from Word.

Comment: Just to clarify, at no point did I say it wasn't possible to open a Word file and then save it as a HTML file from Word. I have no idea why anyone would be doing this in 2022 however. Your Word generated HTML file will have many accessibility issues and won't comply with WCAG AA standards. Additionally, it will offer a poor experience compared to modern SharePoint pages.

Comment: All irrelevant for the present question. There is not the slightest problem with the Word generated HTML page. Contrarily, it is displayed in total perfection in any browser without any issue. Particularly, the beauty of the approach is that you can save the document from Word as HTML by default, which keeps it fully editable in Word AND at the same time ensures that the HTML page is automatically up-to-date at all times.

Comment: You know whenever you save/publish a SharePoint page, it's immediately updated and available instantly? (no need to save it via Word and upload to SharePoint). Accessibility is one of the most important factors in modern web development, your Word generated HTML won't comply and impaired users will struggle to use it. A Word generated HTML file isn't going to offer a better experience to end users than SharePoint pages or any other web content management system.

Comment: Additionally, your solution is entirely static and requires users to update it via Word, while a modern SharePoint page can offer dynamic content which is updated every time you open the page via web parts.

Comment: There are no "users who need to update" anything, but a single Word file that is edited nearly daily by me, which must be available as a single static web page. Thanks for now leaving it to others to answer the *actual* question.

Comment: So there's no reason not to use a SharePoint page? (Other than wanting to use Word). Good luck with this but I can't see it working myself. I can only offer the best practice solution for displaying web content via SharePoint.